# Does Mongoid present any difficulties to scaling?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, performance, mongodb, mongoid, sharding

I am busy designing a web application that will hopefully become very large, with many users. I have chosen MongoDB as a data store, one of the main reasons being its ability to scale horizontally as the user base grows.

Does anyone have any experience using Mongoid to interact with a highly distributed MongoDB handling a lot of traffic? Is there any reason to be concerned about the performance?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So pre 2.0 Mongodb suffered from a global lock, that caused serious problems with scaling. This has been changed in 2.0 for a [Lock with Dynamic yield](http://www.mongodb.org/display/DOCS/How+does+concurrency+work)

> The mongod process uses a modified reader/writer lock with dynamic
>   yielding on page faults and long operations. Any number of concurrent
>   read operations are allowed, but a write operation can block all other
>   operations.

I found some basic performance testing of the [Global Lock vs Lock with Yield](http://java.dzone.com/articles/mongodbs-write-lock).

There is no issue in using Mongoid to access a sharded Mongodb setup. Mongoid just needs to be configured to access the nodes of the shard.

Comment: Please note the salient points of the question: "its ability to scale horizontally" and "a highly distributed MongoDB". In other words, what are the issues with setting up multiple shards, each replicated in a replica-set, with sharding servers in front and with config servers orchestrating the thing?

Answer (score 0):

Mongoid works fine with that because you just need pass all of your instance of MongoDB in database configuration.

Mongoid check to you is the node is master or not and write on it. If master is offline. change master from the MongoDB definition.